# Privacy trust certificate looks outdated

Tags: support, privacy

Banner on the bottom of the [privacy policy page](https://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy) says that certificate is valid today:

> [image: valid today]

But on the [certificate page](https://www.privacytrust.com/cert/878767.html) it looks outdated:

> [image: outdated]

Comment: Yeah, the image is dynamically generated by their server and does not check if it's actually valid or not, the real info appears to be what's written in the "valid until". Looks like SE forgot to renew their trust...

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard no trust SE anymore!

Comment: I'll pass this along internally. Thanks for the report!

Comment: @AdamLear don’t forget to upvote useful reports :)

Comment: @Adam so that's a bug on their side? Or is SE to be blamed for this as well?

Answer (score 2):

Privacy Trust is a third-party contact for resolving disputes. We're following up with them to get the website updated. In the meantime, you can verify that our Privacy Shield certification is valid through August 2018 here: https://www.privacyshield.gov/list.

Comment: Here's a link to SE's page for other interested people -> https://www.privacyshield.gov/participant?id=a2zt00000008P8mAAE&status=Active